# How to get all values corresponding to a key in json having duplicate key-value members?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using jsoncpp to work on a JSON with duplicate key-pair values. My JSON is something like:

```
dict = {
    "a" : "1",
    "b" : "2",
    "c" : "3",
    "a" : "4",
    "c" : "5"
}
```

Even though this JSON looks 'invalid', I want to get a list of values `(1,4)` when `dict["a"]` is accessed. How to get this?

Comment: Probably `jsoncpp` doesn't handle this case and it should tell you, that there are duplicate keys.

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19927061/1147772) might help.