# cannot get data through each()

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

Sorry I'm still quite new to this. I am having trouble getting the data from this array in my ajax success. I am trying to iterate through `productVariantImages` to get the two `imagePath` but I am only able to get one which is from id 496. Below is the sample of the array.

Also if possible I would like to use objects instead of array

```
[1] => Array
    (
      [id] => 194
      [sku] => Apple SKU2
      [variantName] => Pear 2
      [productVariantImages] => Array
      (
         [0] => Array
           (
             [id] => 496
             [imageName] => Apples in season.png
             [imagePath] => http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png
             [visible] => 1
             [featured] => 
             [modifiedDate] => 1448293975
             [createDate] => 1448293975
           )

          [1] => Array
           (
             [id] => 266
             [imageName] => Apples in season.png
             [imagePath] => http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png
             [visible] => 1
             [featured] => 
             [modifiedDate] => 1448293975
             [createDate] => 1448293975
           )

        )
     )
```

My ajax

```
success: function(data){
    ...
    var thumbnails = {};
    $.each(data.productVariantImages,function(i, productVariantImages){
        thumbnails[data.sku] = this.imagePath;    
    });
    ...
 }
```

Current output

```
{Apple SKU2: "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png"}
```

Desired output: Trying to iterate through and get key/value values as shown

```
{Apple SKU2: "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png",
 Apple SKU2: "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png"}
```

Comment: `$.each(data.productVariantImages,function(key, val){
        thumbnails[data.sku] = val;    
 });`

Comment: @Navoneel my console will print out `{Apple SKU2: Object}` instead

Comment: He means `$.each(data.productVariantImages,function(key, val){ thumbnails[data.sku] = val.imagePath; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible what you tried to achieve. An object item key should be unique at all times. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063257/necessity-for-duplicate-keys-in-json-object).

The best solution for you would be an array with the images in it:

```
$.each(data.productVariantImages,function(key, val){ 
    thumbnails.push(val.imagePath);
});
```

getting a single image

```
var imageOne = thumbnails[0];
```

loop through the images

```
for(var thumb in thumbnails) {
// do stuff
}
```