# extract fields from object

Tags: javascript

If I have this:

```
var myObj = [
  { name: 'A', number: 'b1',level: 0 },
  { name: 'B', number: 'b2',level: 0 },
];
```

How can I extract all the names like:

```
"names": {
  'A',
  'B'
}
```

Comment: Its because it is an array

Comment: The desired result isn't a valid object.  You'd probably have to manually build that representation as a string.  It's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Besides you can't have just names: { 'Mike', 'Rik', 'Tom' },  as all values inside names would become key, and they need to have values.

Comment: Seconding what @David said, an object in javascript is like a map in java, meaning there has to be a value mapped to a key. what you want is not a valid object.

Comment: Objects are key-value pairs. So for each key (`'Mike', 'Rik', 'Tom'`) you need a matching value (`'Mike': 'C'`). If you just want a list of "keys" with no matching values, then you want an array.

Comment: @MikeC:I edited my question.If you want to check it .Thanks!

Comment: @David:I edited my question.If you want to check it .Thanks!

Comment: @George Objects can't have duplicate keys. You can't have one object with multiply `name` keys. Maybe you should try telling us what you're actually trying to accomplish, not how you think the data should be formatted.

Comment: @MIkeC:yes,mistake.I removed it.I guess what I want to do can't be done,right?

Comment: @George Why do you think you want an object that only has a bunch of strings in it? What you want is an array and that's totally possible.

Comment: @George: It depends on what you're actually trying to do, a subject on which you've been pretty quiet.  You can't use invalid syntax, that much is certain.  Technically duplicate keys *are* valid syntax, but are pretty useless as far as objects go (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19927061/328193).

Comment: Ok ,thank you all.I will think how to do it right and I will let you know.I know it is possible with arrays

Comment: @MikeC:I opened another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755532/create-object-with-proper-format-from-csv)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to get an *array* of values, not object properties (which are not suited for that):

```js
function getColumn(arr, column) {
    return arr.map(function (rec) { return rec[column] });
}

// Sample data
var myObj = [
  { name: 'A', number: 'b1',level: 0 },
  { name: 'B', number: 'b2',level: 0 },
];

// Get names
var names = getColumn(myObj, 'name');

// Output
console.log(names);
```